# "to do an investigation" or "to make an investigation"?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

> The investigation the detector is going to **make/do** to find out who
>   committed the crime.

Which is more idiomatic, to make or to do an investigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigations are usually [**conducted**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/conduct_1). **Conduct an investigation** is what we call a collocation in English. A collocation is basically a naturally occurring combination of words that are always used side by side in a particular context which means that collocations are by default idiomatic.

An alternative to the expression *conduct an investigation* that will probably work even better in your example would be **to launch an investigation**:

> The investigation the detective is going to **launch** to find out who committed the crime is going to take about eight months.

Comment: @AytAyt I wouldn't say that they mean exactly the same thing, but they're pretty close. **conduct an investigation** is more or less something that you'll often hear legal officials or detectives say (it's a formal procedure). **investigate** is a more general word: **Scientists are investigating the possibility of microbial life in Lake Vostok.**

Answer (score 1):

I think that **Investigate** alone will be the best choice for that specific sentence. I would write:

> The detective will investigate to find out who committed the crime.

Investigate is already a verb which means **"carry out a systematic or formal inquiry to discover and examine the facts of (an incident, allegation, etc.) so as to establish the truth."**

You CAN use conduct or launch to form the sentence:

> The detective will launch/conduct an investigation to find out who committed the crime.

and that would be best if you are talking **specifically** about the action of STARTING the investigation. If you are talking about the investigation itself, I would leave out conduct/launch/make/do/etc, because they make the sentence a bit wordy.

Lastly, as a bit of an aside, I would shy away from that "double the". Your sentence starts with

> **The** investigation **the** [detective] is going to launch/conduct...

which sounds off. You can keep the same format by adding in "that" between the "the" clauses, making it:

> The investigation **that** the [detective] is going to launch/conduct...